# Difference between Classic Satellite DNA and Microsatellites/Minisatellites

Tags: genetics, dna, sequence-analysis, repeatitive-sequence

I am very new to this community and have a basic question about repetitive DNA sequences.

How is different (classic) satellite DNA from microsatellites/minisatellites?

All textbooks give concrete examples of microsatellites and/or minisatellites like --(AC)2--- or ---TACA(TAG)3--TACA----.

Are Classic Satellite DNA just sharing the same properties (perfect, imperfect, compound, complex, di-nucleotides, tri-nucleotides, etc.) as STRs or Minisatellites but the only difference is Classic Satellite DNA are longer?